# Best approach to design our site into hub sites for Home, Departments, HR, IT & Marketing site

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, architecture, hub-site

We have this org structure:-

[image]

so i am planning to create those sites and hub association:-

1. Create a communication site which represent the Home and register it as a Hub
2. Create a communication site which represents the Departments and register it as a Hub
3. Define Home as been the hub site for Departments
4. Create 3 team sites for the HR, IT & Marketing and define Departments site as their hub.

so is my site templates and hub association valid? or it can be improved?

Comment: Will there be any content / pages which will be common to all departments in "departments" site? The content which should be searchable from all sites under?

Comment: @GaneshSanap no the common pages will be under the home site mainly

Comment: So, what will be the purpose of departments site? Different navigation or theme or anything else? If nothing, you may also connect sites directly to main site.

Answer (score 0):

Hub sites provide two primary organizational experiences that you should think about as part of the hub planning process. The organizing concepts for hubs are:

- Association: A site becomes part of a hub family by [Associating a SharePoint site with a hub site](https://support.office.com/article/ae0009fd-af04-4d3d-917d-88edb43efc05).
- Navigation: The hub site owner determines which sites are reflected in the shared navigation and can also include links to other resources. This navigation appears at the top, below the suite bar. Most of the time, you will want to add associated sites to your hub navigation.

**Documentation**: [Planning your SharePoint hub sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/planning-hub-sites)

---

The structure you have defined in your question is fine. But, if you are not going to have content or common pages in "Departments" site, you may also connect HR, IT, etc. sites directly to main/home site.